# How can I send confirmation email from localhost using php email()

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, confirmation

```
php.ini file
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = tuhin.edru@gmail.com
sendmail_path="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

sendmail.ini file
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
auth_username=tuhin.edru@gmail.com
auth_password=0123456789
force_sender=tuhin.edru@gmail.com



$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$dbname="sis";
$conn=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass") or die("could not connect to mysql");

mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);

$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$q1=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into signup_tbl values('$username','$email','$password')");

if($q1)
{

    ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.gmail.com");

    $to = $email; 
    $subject = "Signup | Verification"; 
    $message = " Its a message";                   
    $header = "From: tuhin.edru@gmail.com"; 
    $sentmail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header); 

    if($sentmail)
    {
        echo "successfully sent"
    }

}
```

output:data is uploaded in database but cannot send email.An error message is showed saying

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in

how can i fix this?i have already tried port:587 and 465 but no improvement.plz help me fix this

Comment: not really related to your issue but : you are putting user input right into the SQL query sent to mysql(`"insert into signup_tb1 values('$username',...)"`) So you may encounter SQL injection attack

Comment: `auth_password=01913364536`, you didn't give the **real** password of your gmail account in the question, did you? Update your question and delete it asap!

Comment: no,its not my password..@rajdeep

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to stop using `mail()` function. It likes to cause various problems. In my opinion the better way to send emails is to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library. It provides full SMTP support and some more cool features.

Even with an any error it will be easier to fix your problem when you use tool with big community instead old, rare used function.